# Is this an argument by simplification: it can be done by doing Y, therefore it can be done?

Tags: validity

> The problem is X
> This problem can be easily solved by doing Y
>
> Therefore this problem can be easily solved

I am confused if this is Simplification (Which means the inference is Valid)

Answer (score 3):

No. "Simplification" is typically use for the rule of [conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) in propositional logic. This inference is not even propositional, it requires a predicate S(X,Y), "Y easily solves X", and goes like this S(X,Y) → ∃zS(X,z). This is valid, but not by conjunction elimination. It is called [existential generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization).

In a way, it is similar in spirit: we are going from a more specific statement to a less specific one, as in simplification. [Disjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) and [universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) work that way too. Such inferences in logic are sometimes collectively called "weakening".